# Cannot Populate path in Mongoose while trying to join two documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

#### MongooseError: Cannot populate path `loaned_to` because it is not in your schema. Set the `strictPopulate` option to false to override.

I've tried to join two documents in mongodb using mongoose in nodejs, But unfortunately this error occurs. My mongoose version is 6.0.6

##### Book Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const BookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    "name": {type: String, required: true},
    "author_name": {type: String, required: true},
    "published_date": {type: Date, required: false},
    "copies": [
        {
            "isbn_number": {type: String, required: true},
            "status": {type: String, required: true, default: "Available"},
            "due_back": {type: Date, required: false},
            "loaned_to": {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: false, ref: "User"}
        },
    ]
})

const Book = mongoose.model("Book", BookSchema);
module.exports = Book;
```

##### User Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    "first_name": {type: String, required: true},
    "last_name": {type: String, required: true},
    "phone_number": {type:  String, required: true},
    "address": {type:  String, required: false},
    "user_name":{type: String, required: true},
    "password": {type:  String, required: true},
    "email": {type:  String, required: true},
    "notifications": [
        {
            "notification_id" : {type:"string", required:true},
            "notification": {type: "string", required: true}
        },
    ]
})

const User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

##### My code to join documents

```
exports.getAllBooks = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let data = await BookModel.findOne().populate("loaned_to");
        res.status(200).send({data: [...data], success: true})
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        res.status(404).send({success: false, msg: err.message})
    }
}
```

Comment: path: 'copies.loaned_to' <==== anyone facing this issue . This one is caused due to passing schema name being passed in populate or filed name is wrong.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
exports.getAllBooks = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let data = await BookModel.findOne().populate({
      path: 'copies.loaned_to',
      select:
        'first_name lastName phone_number address user_name email notifications',
    });
    res.status(200).json({ data: [...data], success: true });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({ success: false, msg: err.message });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Use nested populate as in the example below(The example assumes that a Token model has a user which in tern has a role and a role has permissions).
This will return a user object associated with the filtered token, with the role the user is assigned to and the permissions assigned to the role.

That is: TokenModel (has relationship to) -> UserModel (has relationship to) -> RoleModel (has relationship to) -> PermissionsModel)

```
const popObj = {
        path: 'user',
        options: { sort: { position: -1 } },
        populate: {
          path: 'role',
          select: 'name',
          populate: {
            path: 'permissions'
          }
        }
};
const tokenFilter = {is_active: true};
TokenModel.find(userFilter).populate(popObj);
```